# Save NSArray to NSUserDefaults issues (using custom object in array)

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I try to save my object to `NSUserDefaults`. But when I call this method again it is not have any info about previous operation.

There is my method below:

```
- (void)addToCart {
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCart]) {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableArray *products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[prefs objectForKey:kCart]];
        [products addObject:self.product];
        [prefs setObject:products forKey:kCart];
        [prefs synchronize];
        [products release];
    }
    else {
        //Saving...        
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.product, nil] forKey:kCart];
        [prefs synchronize];
    }   
}
```

I need to save a collection with a products to NSUserDefault. I wrap my object to NSArray and save it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything put into `NSUserDefaults` must be a valid property list object (`NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`). All collection elements must themselves also be property list objects.

In order to save non-PL objects into `NSUserDefaults`, you must first convert the object into a PL object. The most generic way to do this is by serializing it to `NSData`.

Serializing to `NSData` is handled with `NSKeyedArchiver`. See [Storing NSColor in User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html) for the canonical example of this. (That document is very old and still references `NSArchiver` which will work fine for this problem, but `NSKeyedArchiver` is now the preferred serializer.)

In order to archive using `NSKeyedArchiver`, your object must conform to `NSCoding` as noted by @harakiri.

Answer (score 2):

You need to conform to the `<NSCoding>` protocol and implement `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` in your custom object.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html